# How do I debug Python Google API interface?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to debug my interface with Google Calendar API v3.  I am writing my code in python and using the API examples I can find.  I want to make sure that I am sending the correct html string to the API.  I see how the code is building the string and inserting parameters, but I don't know what the actual string is getting sent in the `execute()` command.

Is there a way to print the html string that is getting sent rather than executing?  Examples please.

```
http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("moderator", "v1", http=http)

series_body = {
    "description": "Share and rank tips for eating healthy and cheap!",
    "name": "Eating Healthy & Cheap",
    "videoSubmissionAllowed": False
    }

# How Do I print the string rather than execute?
series = service.series().insert(body=series_body).execute()
print "Created a new series"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `httplib2.debuglevel = 4` to print out headers and request/response bodies on stdout:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/Debugging